# How to make autokey be location only

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

In the keyframe menu, I've set it as location keying.

[image]

This works but only if I press I to set a keyframe.

[image]

If I turn on the autokey it keys for locrotscale.

[image]

Comment: I’m not familiar with this panel. What does that button do next to the auto keyframing method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function has been changed over latest versions, in 2.92 you have to activate this preference also:

[image]